# Can android mobile device support the access to WiFi (No internet) and Mobile data which provides internet at the same time?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

Question: I would like to connect android mobile device to WiFi Router (No internet) and to use mobile data simultaneously. The use case is, one android application works on LAN created by WiFi router and other applications (e.g. gmail, youtube etc) work using mobile data. I would like to use all these applications together on a mobile device.

I tried this but I am able to connect to either WiFi or mobile data but not both at the same time. I have used different phones for e.g. Samsung, Redmi running on Android 9, 10, 11. I have got the same results.

Maybe, this question has already been asked many times in the past. I have found answers like the mobile device shall support "Multi path TCP" technology, the mobile device needs to be rooted, the mobile device needs to be in developer option etc.

I don't want to root my phone and I don't want to use developer options.

How to check which phones support this kind of operation? If it is not supported, what can be the limitation - it is a hardware or Android OS which does not support it? How to check all this?

Comment: Multi path TCP is unrelated to what you want. This is more for linking multiple Internet connections for redundancy and speed. Additionally it requires a special multipath server on the Internet that all used Internetconnections address and that unpacks the Multi path TCP stream. Therefore this technology is more like a VPN connection using multiple Internet connections at the same time.